# Empty strings at the beginning and end of split

Tags: ruby, string, perl, split

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Split problem in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453051/split-problem-in-ruby)

In Ruby, when I split a string with a delimiter that matches the beginning of the string, it gives an empty string in the initial position of the array:

```
"abc".split(/a/) # => ["", "bc"]
```

but when I do a similar thing with a delimiter that matches the end of the string, it does not give an empty string:

```
"abc".split(/c/) # => ["ab"]
```

This looks inconsistent to me. Is there any rationale for such specification?

**Edit**
If it is to be compatible with Perl's specification as in muu is to short's answer, then the question remains the same: Why is it like that in Perl? And for this reason, now it also becomes a question about Perl.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11234246/zero-length-string-being-returned-from-stringsplit, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453051/split-problem-in-ruby

Comment: If you want to know Perl's `split` behaves the way it does then you should ask the Perl people. It probably comes from awk and you'd have to Aho, Weinberger, or Kernighan about that.

Comment: Questions asking for rationale are really hard to answer, unless the person making the decision is available to answer, or someone can find a documented statement from the decision-maker or heard them say it. Everything thing else will be opinion or musings, and that makes the question a target for closing.

Comment: @theTinMan That may be the case when a specification is due to the designer's peculiar thinking. But I thought that the more trusted and widely accepted the specification/language is, the more likely it is that (especially the experienced) user community share some understanding of why it is so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading AWK's specification following mu is too short, I came to feel that the original intention for `split` in AWK was to extract substrings that correspond to fields, each of which is terminated by a punctuation mark like `,`, `.`, and the separator was considered something like an "end of field character". The intention was not splitting a string symmetrically into the left and the right side of each separator position, but was terminating a substring on the left side of a separator position. Under this conception, it makes sense to always have some string (even if it is empty) on the left of the separator, but not necessarily on the right side of the separator. This may have been inherited to Ruby via Perl.

Answer (score 9):

From the [fine manual](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-split):

> **split(pattern=$;, [limit]) → anArray**
>   [...]
>   If the *limit* parameter is omitted, trailing null fields are suppressed. If *limit* is a positive number, at most that number of fields will be returned (if *limit* is 1, the entire string is returned as the only entry in an array). If negative, there is no limit to the number of fields returned, and trailing null fields are not suppressed.

So trailing "null fields" are suppressed because the documentation says they are. If you want the trailing empty string, ask for it:

```
'abc'.split(/c/, -1) # [ 'ab', '' ]
```

Why would it behave that way? Probably because it matches [Perl's `split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) behavior:

> If `LIMIT` is negative, it is treated as if it were instead arbitrarily large; as many fields as possible are produced.

and we see that using a negative `limit`, again, gives us the trailing empty string:

```
$ perl -e 'print join(",", split(/c/, "abc")), "\n"'
ab
$ perl -e 'print join(",", split(/c/, "abc", -1)), "\n"'
ab,
```

Why copy Perl's behavior? Ask Matz.

Comment: We might as well ask Larry Wall. Your answer is not a complete answer to my question, but is an important step towards it.